# Header not at top of the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I try to clone a website's front end to improve my knowledge.
The problem is Header is not at the top of this website.
Im new to bootstrap but i have to control it.
I did reset the CSS.
It's my first time here, I'm appreciated your help.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.img {
    width: 221px;
    height: 56px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="logo" class="pb-2">
        <img class="float-start py-2 ps-1 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar pe-4 pb-3" id="sidebar">
        <!--sidebar start-->
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand mx-4 mb-3"></a>
                <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-laptop me-2"></i>Admin</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent border-0">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">B</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">C</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
                </div>        
<!--sidebar end-->
    </div>
    <header class="sticky-top">
        <h1>CHƯƠNG TRÌNH REBATE</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-bell me-lg-2"></i>
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/aTu.png" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
        <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-flex">TuNTC23</span>
        <hr>
    </header>
```

Comment: What are you trying to get it to look like?

Comment: header to the top and next to the logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved some code around and managed to get it looking somewhere close, make sure you are pulling in the correct imports in you  tag, like
Bootstrap 5 or 4 etc...

(SECOND ATTEMPT)

```
header {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.dropdown-item {
  background-color: red!important;
}

.sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 200px; 
  border-right: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```
 <head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 </div>
    <header class="flex flex-col sticky-top">
      <div id="logo" class="pb-2">
        <img class="float-start py-2 ps-1 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
        <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
        <h1>CHƯƠNG TRÌNH REBATE</h1>
        <i class="fa fa-bell me-lg-2"></i>
        <img class="rounded-circle" src="assets/img/aTu.png" alt="" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;">
        <span class="d-none d-lg-inline-flex">TuNTC23</span>
        <hr>
    </header>

    <div class="sidebar pe-4 pb-3" id="sidebar">
        <!--sidebar start-->
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand mx-4 mb-3"></a>
                <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
                    <div class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-laptop me-2"></i>Admin</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent border-0">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">B</a>
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">C</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="sidebar">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
                </div>   
      </div>
<!--sidebar end-->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I would consider your options as there are a few ways of doing this, this way is preferred by me but not everyone.

Firstly we fixed the element so its stays where it is, next we apply top:0 to make sure the element is at the top of the page and finally passing  'width: 100%' to ensure the navigation fills the width entirely.

I can help more if this answer is not enough.

Comment: I intend to make the navbar become a sidebar ( I mean the navbar stay on the left )  
Then on the top, I want to make the logo remain on the left and the header be next to it.
Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it.

I do as you said but the header is still under the sidebar, help me 

Comment: Check my updated comment, I think it may be somewhere near what you wanted. ^

Comment: If my answer assisted you in anyway would you be so kind as to hit the 'tick' to accept this as a valid answer. Kind Regards and happy coding. ;)

Comment: Of course, I'm so sorry I didn't do it sooner.
Your answer completely solves my problem.
Thank you so much and happy coding as well. 

Comment: Your welcome... Take care :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).